# Ethernet controller behavior in micro-controller described correctly?

Tags: controller, embedded, ethernet

I am reading the book "Embedded Software Development: the Open Source approach", 2015 edition. On pages 28-29 there is the following sentence:

> As said previously, the bus segments shown as dashed vertical lines
>   somewhat deviate from the regular structure of the crossbar and are
>   used by components (for instance, the Ethernet controller) that can be
>   both bus masters and slaves.This kind of behavior is needed in some
>   cases because, continuing the example concerning the Ethernet
>   controller,
>
> - It must be able to autonomously read from memory and write into memory the frames to be transmitted and being received, respectively,
>     and also
> - It must allow the processor to read and write its internal registers, to access status information and control its behavior,
>     respectively.

The writing of the above sentence is an example to avoid, because "it" may refer to the Ethernet-controller or the processor, when "it" appears on the 2nd bullet point.

I am wondering what is the meaning of the sentence, and I have the following interpretation, so I want to know if it is correct:

....This kind of behavior is needed in some cases because, continuing the example concerning the Ethernet controller,

- the Ethernet controller must be able to autonomously read from memory the frames to be transmitted and write into memory the frames being received, and also
- the Ethernet controller must allow the processor to read the Ethernet controller's internal registers to access the Ethernet controller's status information and also allow the processor to write on the Ethernet controller's internal registers so that the processor can control the Ethernet controller's behavior.

So have I got it correct? Does the Ethernet controller have internal registers? And does the Eth.-con. allow the Processor to read these internal registers? Does the Eth.-con. allow the processor to write on them too?

Comment: I dont have the book and a brief about the chapter may be useful. I think that it is talking about peripherals in a microcontroller (I mean, inside the chip) which have to share registers (peripheral's registers) with the CPU (even with another peripherals). Going further, it might be an introduction to explain simultaneous memory access, data races, blocked buses, mutex, semaphores...

Comment: Ethernet transceivers have internal MII registers that can be read with `SIOCGMIIREG` in `linux`. MII registers are described in IEEE 802.11 standard. Also, on many systems [`memory mapped input-output`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) techniques are used so that addresses of MII register are mapped directly to physical addresses that can be accessed on `linux` with `/dev/mem`.

Comment: It seems semantically clear to me the introduction ends _"...  concerning the Ethernet controller,"_ followed by two bullet points referring to the Ethernet controller ("it").  Either way this is an English comprehension question about hardware - not a software question at all, so not an SO question.  All I/O peripherals (that are in any way software configurable) have registers; if your Ethernet controller is on an MCU you can certainly write to them, and if it is external, the controller will be on the system bus - if it is not it will never work.

Comment: @JoseFelipe : It does not matter at all whether the  controller is on-chip or external; it will still be bus-mapped and will have registers - all peripheral I/O that are in any way devices have registers - these are not related to the CPU registers.

Comment: Strictly, if I were picky, since the introduction ends in a comma, the bullet points should each start with lower-case "i" and the first one should end in a comma - they form part of the same sentence.

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes. You understand correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is described as "it must be able to read from and write to memory the frames..." is a typical example of a DMA-capable device that can hold the CPU and take over the bus to directly read and write system memory.

Obviously, the CPU must be able to tell the network card stuff like the address filters to use, and the memory ranges it should transmit frames from and receive frames into, and it must tell the network card when to start a transfer - This information is written by the CPU into controller registers that are normally mapped into the I/O address range of the CPU. This is the normal way of the CPU controlling what the peripherals do - and applies to hard disk and floppy controllers, USB and RTC peripherals as well.

Comment: I suppose that what I wrote as my interpretation is correct then ( I am not 100% sure from your answer). Just have in mind that I am just learning about these things now for the first time , so I did not understood the details of your reply, it created more questions (for example: you say "and the memory ranges it should transmit frames from and receive frames into" , and I ask : what is that memory you mention? the SRAM of the microcontroller? some memory of the Ethernet component , which I still do not know if it exists? Some memory on the CPU , like cache or something else? )

Comment: DMA goes to and fro the main memory of the *system* - So, physically, your RAM chips. Memory on peripherals typically does exist, in the form of a (limited number) of registers that can be read and written by the CPU.